# Merging two array of objects and its properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have two arrays which I want to merge.

```
var arrayOne = [{id:1},{id:2}];
var arrayTwo = [{age: 20}, {age: 25}, {age: 22}];
```

Merged array should be like this

```
[{id:1, age: 20}, {id:2, age: 25}, {age: 22}]
```

I have tried _.zip method from underscore library but it only merges array and not array of objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
var merged = arrayTwo.map((o, i) => Object.assign({}, o, (arrayOne[i] || {})));
```

Comment: thats why I love stackoverflow. amazing solution

Comment: you can even skip the `(arrayOne[i] || {})` Object.assign() can deal with undefined values `(o,i) => Object.assign({}, o, arrayOne[i])`

Comment: This only works if you know that arrayTwo is longer than arrayOne.

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou `var arr = [arrayOne, arrayTwo, ..,  arrayN].sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
var curr = arr.shift();
var merged = curr.map((o, i) => ( arr.forEach(prop => (o = Object.assign({}, o, prop[i]))), o));`

Answer (score 2):

something more general:

```
function merge(...arrays){
  var length = arrays.reduce((len, arr) => Math.max(len, arr.length), 0);
  var assign = i => (into, arr) => Object.assign(into, arr[i]);
  return Array.from({ length }, (v,i) => arrays.reduce(assign(i), {}));
}

var arrayOne = [{id:1},{id:2}];
var arrayTwo = [{age: 20}, {age: 25}, {age: 22}];

merge(arrayOne, arrayTwo /*or as many as you want*/ );
```

Answer (score 1):

An ES6 approach:

```
const mergeArrays = (arr1, arr2) => {
    if (arr2.length > arr1.length) [arr1,arr2] = [arr2, arr1] //swap: larger first
    return arr1.map( (item, idx) => Object.assign({}, item, arr2[idx]) )
}

mergeArrays(
    [{id:1},{id:2}], [{age: 20}, 
    {age: 25}, {age: 22}]
)
//[ { age: 20, id: 1 }, { age: 25, id: 2 }, { age: 22 } ]

mergeArrays(
    [{age: 20}, {age: 25}, {age: 22}],
    [{id:1},{id:2}]
)
//[ { age: 20, id: 1 }, { age: 25, id: 2 }, { age: 22 } ]
```

Note that length can be different and order doesn't matter (you can pass the bigger array after or before, the result is the same).

Answer (score 1):

```
function zipObjects() {
    return _.zip.apply(_, arguments).map(
        function(arr) {
            return _.extend.apply(_, [{}].concat(arr));
        }
    );
}
```

or in ES6:

```
function zipObjects(...args) {
    return _.zip(...args).map(
        (arr) => _.extend({}, ...arr)
    );
}
```

Comment: While it can be done nicely in vanilla, this is the only answer with underscore, which is tagged in the question. What's nice here is that, while you've encapsulated it as a function, you could just run it in a one-liner if you don't need to do it very much. e.g. `const myZipped = _.zip(arrayOne, arrayTwo).map((arr) => _.extend({}, ...arr));`

Answer (score 0):

Good use case for a generator with object spread props:

```
function* zip(...args) {
  const len = Math.max(...args.map(a => a.length));
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      yield Object.assign({}, ...args.map(a => a[i]));
  }
}
```

This will yield an iterator, not an array, so you can get an array result with a simple `Array.from` or an array spread, like so

```
var arrayOne = [{id:1},{id:2}];
var arrayTwo = [{age: 20}, {age: 25}, {age: 22}];

console.log([...zip(arrayTwo, arrayOne)]);
```

edit: if you don't love yielding, you can map from a new array built to the longest length. Works with any ordering of arrays, and any number of arrays of objects.

```
const zipAr = (...args) => Array
.from({ length: Math.max(...args.map(a => a.length)) })
.map((_, i) => Object.assign({}, ...args.map(a => a[i])));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Object.assign()** would be a key method for merging objects..

**Example:**

```
var arrayOne = [{id:1},{id:2}];
var arrayTwo = [{age: 20}, {age: 25}, {age: 22}];


//Lets assume that we want to update arrayTwo ..

for(var i = 0 ; i < arrayOne.length; i++){
   arrayTwo[i] = Object.assign(arrayTwo[i] , arrayOne[i])
}


console.log(arrayTwo);
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one liner code using [**array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & [**Object.assign()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method **.**

**DEMO**

```js
var arrayOne = [{id:1},{id:2}];
var arrayTwo = [{age: 20}, {age: 25}, {age: 22}];

var res = arrayTwo.map(function(item, index) { return Object.assign(item, arrayOne[index]);
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function compareMyArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo){
  var newArray = [];
  var maxCounter = (arrayOne.lenght > arrayTwo.length) ? arrayOne.length : arrayTwo.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
    var value1 = null;
    if(arrayOne.length-1 <= i){
      value1 = arrayOne[i];
    }
    var value2 = null;
      if(arrayOne.length-1 <= i){
      value1 = arrayOne[i];
    }
    if(!!value1 && !! value2){
      newArray[i] = {value1, value2}
    } else if(!!value1) {
      newArray[i] = {value1}
    } else if(!!value2) {
      newArray[i] = {value2}
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

returns exactly what you are looking for, but only works if both arrays have the same length

Edit: now works with array in different lengths too